# moz-document url-prefix not working for hyperlink

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have css called action1 and i trying to remove outline property from it just for firefox browser. Here is the class

```
a.action1,a.action1:link,a.action1:visited {
    display: block;
    height: 27px;
    width: 200px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #666633;
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    outline: 1px solid #666633;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #888;
}
```

and here is the code i am using in my jsp to remove the outline property

```
<style>
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    a.action1 {
        outline: 0px;
    }
}
</style>
```

This is not working for.

```
<a class="action1" onclick="dosomething()" href="gosomewhere">somename</a>
```

Although moz-document is working perfectly fine for input type button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@-moz-document not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803319/moz-document-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebug to check whether the css is applied, whether it has lower priority level than others.

Try

```
<style>
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    a.action1 {
        outline: 0 none !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: This worked. I had the outline defined in a common css file which gets included first in jsp page and then i had the firefox override defined in the jsp page. SO i thought the one in the JSP page should get applied. I dont know on what basis browsers apply CSS styles. Thanks muzuiget.

Comment: Unfortunately, I fear, as of Firefox 59 this won't work anymore: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1035091