# @-moz-document not working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

In the end, I want firefox and chrome to display the same way. On chrome I've noticed that `float: left` breaks the site but works on FF. However, if I put `float:none` Chrome displays perfectly but then it is broken on FF.

I have tried `@-moz-document url-prefix() {.attempt{float:left}}` but that appears not to be working. I've tried `@document url() {.attempt{float:left}}` but that doesn't help either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<style>
  @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .attempt {
      float:left
    }
  }
  .attempt {
    float:none
  }
</style>

<div class="attempt">someText</div>
```

Also [It has been asked before with no answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794423/moz-document-url-prefix-not-working)

Comment: Answering this question because the linked question has some subtle differences which actually make it much more difficult to reproduce than this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the surface it would seem to be because your `@-moz-document` appears before the `float:none` rule — so it will always get overridden regardless. The presence of a conditional at-rule does not change how the cascade works; this is a [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306670/css-specificity-media-queries-and-min-width/10322199#10322199) [gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241531/what-are-the-rules-for-css-media-query-overlap/13611538#13611538) with `@media` rules and applies just as well to `@-moz-document`.

You want to move it to the bottom so it will override the previous rule properly in Firefox:

```
<style>
  .attempt {
    float:none
  }
  @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .attempt {
      float:left
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="attempt">someText</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2018, the answer @BoltClock gave has [been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794423/moz-document-url-prefix-not-working#answer-51675187).  The solution is a  media query ( seen below ):

```
@media screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #logo {
        padding-top: 1.5rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's been deprecated too. They brought back support for @-moz-document for targeting Firefox a few months ago, they simply recommend against it unless there is a specific need to. -moz-device-pixel-ratio is at least as old if not older. If it is new, it's only a handful of versions newer, not 2018 new.

Comment: I couldn't find any resources saying @-moz-document support was brought back, only that support was dropped May 2018.  Do you have a reference saying support is back?

Comment: The release notes for Fx 61 only mention dropping support for the feature in general, but the @-moz-document url-prefix() hack will continue to work, as in [this ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1446470).